# Given desired results and database information, programically build an SQL query that gives those results

Tags: sql, algorithm

I don't think there's an easy way to do this, but on the off chance that there is ...

I am given a number of lists of around 10000 records each from a 10 million record table. The data is currently generated by queries on various non-indexed elements. I want to automatically build queries that give the same results, using ten separate indexed fields.

Is there a known algorithm for building something like this? Beyond the basics of including each indexed 'node' with its own OR, I mean.

E.g., assuming the data wanted is:

```
Letter, Number
A, 1
A, 2
B, 1
C, 2
```

and the original database has

```
Letter, Number
A, 1
A, 2
A, 3
B, 1
C, 1
C, 2
D, 1
D, 3
```

I'd like something like:

```
WHERE ((Letter = 'A' OR Letter = 'B') AND (Number = 1 OR Number = 2)) 
OR (Letter = 'C' and Number = 2)
```

Or maybe

```
WHERE (Letter IN ('A', 'B', 'C') AND Number IN (1, 2) 
AND NOT (Number = 1 AND Letter = 'C'))
```

But I *think* I'd rather not have

```
WHERE (Letter = 'A' AND Number = '1') OR 
(Letter = 'A' AND Number = '2') OR
(Letter = 'B' AND Number = '1') OR
(Letter = 'C' AND Number = '2')
```

-- unless the database experts here think that that would be much more optimized in the long term, for the sample size we're talking about. Run time of the queries is important; run time of the conversion tool is not. I also don't need to necessarily get the 'best' answer; 'good enough' is acceptable.

My current plan is to count, sort and iterate through looking for things that can be grouped together, to try to make as few 'groupings' as possible; I think I'd rather not have ten thousand (A and B and C and D and E and F and G and H and I and J)'s ORed together.

Thoughts? Expert advice?

Comment: Any thoughts on how to tag this, also appreciated. It's not really an SQL question, as much as a language-agnostic question that happens to take place in an SQL-space. I should probably separate the musing on optimization to somewhere else; I'm more interested in the algorithm, here.

Comment: I added the 'algorithm' tag. There might be a specific, named algorithm or named problem that fits this, but I don't know what it might be.

Comment: All of those queries will result in an equivalent query plan on most databases. DBs can't do disjunctions efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is not really an answer to your question, but rather my own musings on the problem.

I'd suggest storing your lists in a separate table. That'll enable you to do a joined select from the two tables in the end. You may or may not use indexes on the filter table, depending on the performance tests with your data.

The exact implementation would differ given the particular RDMBS you intend to use. In my example I'll stick to Oracle, as it's what I know best.

```
CREATE TABLE t_filter_lists (
    f_letter varchar2(1),
    f_number number
);

-- Optionally, create an index:
CREATE INDEX ix_filter_lists
ON t_filter_lists (
    f_letter,
    f_number
);

INSERT INTO t_filter_lists (f_letter, f_number) VALUES ('A', 1);
INSERT INTO t_filter_lists (f_letter, f_number) VALUES ('A', 2);
INSERT INTO t_filter_lists (f_letter, f_number) VALUES ('B', 1);
INSERT INTO t_filter_lists (f_letter, f_number) VALUES ('C', 2);
COMMIT;

-- (Oracle-specific part) gather statistics on the filter table
EXEC DMBS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(...

-- Run your query
SELECT *
FROM t_your_table t
    INNER JOIN t_filter_lists f
        ON  f.f_letter = t.t_letter
        AND f.f_number = t.t_number;
```

The benefit of this solution is that, given that the table and index statistics are complete and fresh, you will not have the headache to choose the correct order of the predicates depending on which and how columns are indexed, in which order, what is their estimated cardinality etc. The optimizer will do that work for you, and it should be quite good at it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use Except on the scenarios you do not want:

```
Select Letter, Number
From Table
Except
    (
    Select 'A', 3
    Union All 
    Select 'C', 1
    Union All 
    Select Distinct 'D', Number
    From Table
    )
```

Another solution would be to simply populate a temporary table with the list of excluded values and use Except against that.

**Addition**

The nature of the algorithm used to determine your criteria is not clear. Will it be finding items to include or exclude? My initial two solutions presume you are building a list of exclusions. However, if you are building a list of inclusions then obviously you can use Intersect instead. In addition, you might be able to make the list smaller by using the Values constructor:

```
Select Letter, Number
From Table
Intersect
Select *
From ( Values('A',1)
    , ('A',2), ('A',3), ('B',1), ('C',2) )
```

As with the Except scenario, it will likely be faster to populate a temp table with the combination you want and query against that.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really possible without more constraints on the problem. There's a literally infinite number of filter criteria you could use to select a set of rows from a database, and it's simply not possible to evaluate them all. For instance, suppose the view is constructed from rows whose IDs are prime, or whose SHA1 hashes end with 0 - would you reasonably expect any automated procedure to be able to discover these rules?

Further, given only the rows that match, there's no way be sure any rule you build won't also select additional records from the database that don't match - the positive set alone is not enough.

Comment: You have the database information. And no, I wouldn't expect it to pick up on the primes -- the point is, that there ISN'T a "Right Answer" available from the data. It's a mess of mostly-random data and I want to find rules to describe it based on the indexed fields.

Comment: @Trevel So is generating mostly-right answers acceptable? Are false positives okay? False negatives? What should the system do if it can't find a solution?

Comment: Identifiable false positives/negatives are acceptable, as is saying "there's no good answer."